# Can't figure out why content inside of my div is getting scrunched when the div collapses

Tags: css, reactjs

Here is the link to the portfolio page I'm currently working on in react. When you collapse a div the content gets scrunched and I'm not sure what the solution to this is. I thought it was "white-space: nowrap;" but that doesn't seem to be doing anything for me. I'm sure it's something super simple but can't pinpoint what's happening.

Appreciate any help. Thank you!

https://goresometimes.netlify.app/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens as the width of your content drawer is 100% and the content flows dynamically to this width. You'll want to use fixed width like `width: 100vw` on relevant container elements instead. The actual value needs to be adjusted according to what you need*

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That solved the problem. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

remove height:100% on .navbox also remove in media query

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but removing the height percentage will actually reduce the size of the container that's expanding to render the content. I appreciate the help.